# Code - Spell check extension - where to add/remove dictionaries?

Tags: code, language, extensions

I would like to use spell check extension in Code but have not find any place, how to add/remove languages (dictionaries).
Can you help me, where is the config for this extension, and/or where to upload dict. files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to help with this one:

First, obviously, enable the extension in Code's Preferences.

[image]

Now, right-clicking inside a document will let you choose from one of the pre-existing languages:

[image]

If, like me, you might need a language that is not in the list, you can easely add it if you have the available dictonary files. The extension 'looks' for available languages inside `/usr/share/hunspell/`. Inside this folder, every language is represented by two files: .dic & .tiff.

One way to add new languages is by simply running a `sudo apt install language` command. For example, running `sudo apt install hunspell-ro` will add a new `ro_RO`entry to the 'Languages' menu in Code, and enable spell-checking for the Romanian language. I used [this ArchWiki](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=hunspell-) for a list of available extra language packs.

Another way is to simply copy the .dic & .tiff files (if you have them already from other sources) to `/usr/share/hunspell/`. There are numerous repositories online where you could get maybe updated? dictionaries. The [LibreOffice dictionaries GitHub repo](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries) seems to contain some extra languages...

Comment: Vlad, Thank you!
_excellent answer_